# Update Rails to Hotwire Gives a 304

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

I've updated a Rails '6.0.3' app to use `hotwire-rails` rather than `turbolinks` and am getting a 304 for the response with no update to the view within the `turbo_frame_tag`

I created a new Rails app from scratch and implemented hotwire successfully so I'm guessing the issue is with residual Javascript in my existing app.

### Server request

The server request matches that of the new app so it doesn't appear to be the issue, note the 200 status code.

```
Started GET "/models/1/edit" for ::1 at 2021-01-18 13:33:22 +1100
Processing by ModelsController#edit as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Model Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE "models"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/models_controller.rb:15:in `edit'
  Rendering models/edit.haml
  Rendered models/edit.haml (Duration: 1.1ms | Allocations: 1500)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 4244)
```

### Browser

The browser response seems to be identical except for the status code being 304 rather than 200 and obviously no view change rendered.

[image]

### Steps to recreate

- Existing Rails '6.0.3' app
- Update Gemfile to remove `tubolinks` and `webpacker`
- `trash app/javascript`
- `trash node_modules/**`
- `rails hotwire:install`

### Extra info

When I ran `rails hotwire:install` I get a `File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  app/assets/config/manifest.js` message - I've checked the file and it's identical to the one generated in the new app.

Comment: Hi @vladiim , do you have a repo for debugging?